# About Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, time

According to relativty as we get close to Speed of light time expands. So my question: in movies people go to another planets and then time gets slower for them and when they come back their friends stay young etc. Isn’t that fake, i mean to experience time expansion don’t we have to go really fast? But also when i make a pendulum with period 2 in world then i go to another planet and use this pendulum to measure time i measure different. This phenomenon is not related to time expansion right ? Or is it ?
P.S : i’m not studying physics just a guy in highschool..

Comment: What movie are you referring to? You might also need to consider General Relativity, and the fact that in your frame you will never measure your own time differently.

Comment: Movie physics $\ne$ real physics.

Comment: @StephenG This is a good rule of thumb, but sometimes movie physics lines up with real physics though. I think it is also a very good way to learn about physics in looking at why things that happen in movies are correct/incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The wein apradox is actually opposite: you're younger when you come back to Earth. The thing is that, if you go back, then you have o constant velocity, and so special relativity doesn't apply.

As for the pendulum, the period depends on the gravity. If you're quiet, gravity defines the period. However, on the same gravitational field, different observers (moving with relative velocity $v=const$) will measure different periods due to time dilation, and both are correct.